# Render a subset of model elements in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

We need to be able to render a subset of BIM model elements and also dynamically color some elements. Based on [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only) article it looks like it’s possible to render a subset of elements given you can provide a list of their dbIds. It also looks like Forge viewer API uses dbIds to interact with rendered elements.

Before converting the BIM model to SVF2, we assign our own ids to model elements. I can see our own ids as properties of model objects when accessing the properties database of the model in the browser. It would be great if we could generate a list of associations between our ids and forge dbIds.

Does autodesk provide an API to fetch custom properties or is there a way to correlate the dbId at upload time?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this endpoint [GET Properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) from the `ModelDerivative` API and search for your own id in properties.
You will get the `dbid` of your object and then build your collection of associations.

Comment: Note that you can access the design properties in other ways as well: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer.

Comment: Hey @PetrBroz, I followed the blog post you shared and downloaded sqlite file for one of our models, but it doesn't look like dbIds (_objects_id.id) from the sqlite file match dbIds that forge viewer fetches when displaying the model. I used `viewer.model.getPropertyDb` to see data that forge fetches.

Comment: Also, I can't use GET Properties API since it only fetches up to 800mb and the models that we work with can be bigger than that

Comment: Be careful about the SVF1 vs SVF2 difference. These two file formats use different ID generation schema. The sqlite file contains SVF1 dbids, so if you're loading the SVF2 format in the viewer, the dbids won't match. See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/temporary-workaround-mapping-between-svf1-and-svf2-ids.